# Linq or Tsql 'Pivot'

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, pivot

I'm sure this is covered elsewhere but I'm having some problems figuring out an elegant solution for this.

```
ID  C     D
1   Apple Red
1   Pear  Orange
2   Apple Red 
2   Pear  Orange
```

What I am trying to end up with is this:

```
ID  | Benefit | Value
1   | C       | Apple
1   | C       | Pear
2   | C       | Apple
2   | C       | Pear
1   | D       | Red
1   | D       | Orange
2   | D       | Red
2   | D       | Orange
```

I can do it in Linq by scanning each column and adding to the List.

```
public class SampleRow
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String A { get; set; }
    public String B { get; set; }        
}

public class SampleOutput
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Description { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }  

}

        List<SampleRow> rows = new List<SampleRow>();
        rows.Add(new SampleRow
        {
            Id = 1,
            A = "Apple",
            B = "Red"
        });
        rows.Add(new SampleRow
        {
            Id = 1,
            A = "Pear",
            B = "Orange"
        });
        rows.Add(new SampleRow
        {
            Id = 2,
            A = "Apple",
            B = "Red"
        });
        rows.Add(new SampleRow
        {
            Id = 2,
            A = "Pear",
            B = "Orange"
        });


        List<SampleOutput> output = new List<SampleOutput>();
        rows.ForEach(row =>
            output.Add(new SampleOutput()
            {
                Id = row.Id,
                Description = "A",
                Value = row.A
            })
            );
        rows.ForEach(row =>
            output.Add(new SampleOutput()
            {
                Id = row.Id,
                Description = "B",
                Value = row.B
            })
            );
```

I'm wondering if there's a better way. I'm open to Linq or TSQL solutions. The data is stored in SQL like the first table/object list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that a clean and elegant solution is to use UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT
  ID, Benefit, Value
FROM
  Test
UNPIVOT
  (Value FOR Benefit IN (C, D)) unpvt
ORDER BY
  Benefit, ID
```

Here you have a working demo
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/12884/9

Hope this helps

Comment: Most of members forget about Unpivot operator ;)

Answer (score 2):

Via using Linq you can achieve that in a simpler manner:

```
var qry = rows.Select(c=>new{ID = c.ID, Benefit="C", Value=c.C})
        .Concat(rows.Select(d=>new{ID = d.ID, Benefit="D", Value=d.D}));
```

A result set can be "converted" into datatable by using [CopyToDataTable() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.copytodatatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[EDIT]`Union` has been replaced by `Concat` - as [danihp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/842935/danihp) suggested in comments[/EDIT]

Comment: What about `Concat` instead `Union` ?

Comment: @danihp, It should produce the same result ;)

Comment: OP talks about elegant approach. From the semantic point of view, in my opinion, this is a concat. Also, concat may be translated as `Union all` SQL sentence, avoid look for duplicates, perhaps more performance (?)

Comment: @danihp, i haven't tested which solution is faster, but i think the time of execution might be similar...

Comment: It seems your last comment confirm my theory ;) Two points: more readable and faster.

Comment: I ended up going with Unpivot but I also really liked this solution.